# Deriving a recursion relation for Clebsch-Gordan coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory

I refer to [Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics](https://emc2physics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/J.-J.-Sakurai_-Jim-Napolitano-Modern-Quantum-Mechanics-2021-Cambridge-University-Press-libgen.li_.pdf). Using the lower signs for equation $3.369$ on page $212$,

$$\sqrt{(j+m)(j-m+1)}\langle j_{1}j_{2};m_{1}m_{2} | j_{1}j_{2};j,m-1\rangle =  \sqrt{(j_{1}+m_{1}+1)(j_{1}-m_{1})}\langle j_{1}j_{2};m_{1}+1,m_{2} | j_{1}j_{2};jm\rangle + \sqrt{(j_{2}+m_{2}+1)(j_{2}-m_{2})}\langle j_{1}j_{2};m_{1},m_{2}+1 | j_{1}j_{2};jm\rangle $$

We want to add the spin and orbital angular momenta of a spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particle.We set $j_{1} = l, m_{1} = m_{l}, j_{2} =s = \frac{1}{2}$ and $m_{2} = m_{s} = \pm\frac{1}{2}$.Sakurai works out the above recursion relation for the case $j = l + \frac{1}{2} (j_{1} = l, j_{2} = \frac{1}{2})$. Here, $m_{1} = m_{l} = m-\frac{1}{2}, m_{2} = m_{s} = \frac{1}{2}$.

When I plug these values for $m_{1}, m_{2}$ and $j$ in, I get the following recursion relation (suppressing $j_{1},j_{2}$):

$$ \sqrt{\Big(l+\frac{1}{2} +m\Big)\Big(l+\frac{1}{2} -m +1\Big)} \Big\langle m-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \Big| l+\frac{1}{2}, m-1 \Big\rangle \notag \\= \sqrt{\Big(l+ m -\frac{1}{2} +1\Big)\Big(l -m +\frac{1}{2}\Big)} \Big\langle m+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \Big| l+\frac{1}{2}, m \Big\rangle $$

But equation $3.374$ on page $214$ gives us:
$$ \sqrt{\Big(l+\frac{1}{2} +m +1\Big)\Big(l+\frac{1}{2} -m \Big)} \Big\langle m-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \Big| l+\frac{1}{2}, m \Big\rangle \notag \\= \sqrt{\Big(l+ m +\frac{1}{2}\Big)\Big(l -m +\frac{1}{2}\Big)} \Big\langle m+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \Big| l+\frac{1}{2}, m+1 \Big\rangle$$

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you went wrong is comparing apples and oranges. Your superb text is right.

By the time it utilized (3.369), it "translated" the unconventional (3.370) into the standard convention, (3.375). You may do this in your head by adding $m_1+m_2$ of the Clebsches and matching that to $m'-1$ or $m$ in the latter expressions. I am using $m'=m+1$ for the unconventional choice, and $m$ for the conventional one.

Before you lose your mind, I translate, below, (3.369) to the conventional nomenclature, so, then,
$$\sqrt{(j+m+1)(j-m)}\langle j_{1}j_{2};m_{1}m_{2} | j_{1}j_{2};j,m\rangle \\ =  \sqrt{(j_{1}+m_{1}+1)(j_{1}-m_{1})}\langle j_{1}j_{2};m_{1}+1,m_{2} | j_{1}j_{2};j~~m+1\rangle \\ + \sqrt{(j_{2}+m_{2}+1)(j_{2}-m_{2})}\langle j_{1}j_{2};m_{1},m_{2}+1 | j_{1}j_{2};j~~m+1\rangle . \tag{3.369a}$$

When you plug the same  values  into *it*, so you firmly live in (3.375)-land, you find the correct text expression,
$$ \sqrt{\Big(l+\frac{1}{2} +m +1\Big)\Big(l+\frac{1}{2} -m \Big)} \Big\langle m-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \Big| l+\frac{1}{2}, m \Big\rangle \notag \\ = \sqrt{\Big(l+ m +\frac{1}{2}\Big)\Big(l -m +\frac{1}{2}\Big)} \Big\langle m+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \Big| l+\frac{1}{2}, m+1 \Big\rangle. \tag{ 3.374 }$$

Comment: Right, I get it. The $m$ in the formula (3.369a) is basically the sum of $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ minus or plus one (in this case plus) and not the constant $m$ used in $m_{1} = m-\frac{1}{2}$. I was wondering myself why $m_{1} + m_{2}$ did not satisfy condition 3.3.70! Thank you!

Comment: Ehm.. in 3.369a,   $m=m_1+m_2$, whereas in your beginning formula, 3.369, $m_1+m_2= m-1$. But you get the drift...

Comment: I called the latter $m'=m+1$ to avoid the confusion...